# Correct way to implement fire and forget async method call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, task

In my project, I have a network call to sending Email, I don't want to wait for the response, because the most likely Email provider sends the Emails successfully. Which of the following methods is better and what is the difference?

**`Method 1`**: await `SendAsync` and use `Task.Run`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    await SendAsync();
    return View();
}

private Task SendAsync()
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Before");
        await Task.Delay(10000); // Email send
        _logger.LogInformation("After");
    });

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**`Method 2`**: Does not await `SendAsync`

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    SendAsync();
    return View();
}

private async Task SendAsync()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Before");
    await Task.Delay(10000);  // Email send
    _logger.LogInformation("After");
}
```

Both methods work with awaiting in `Task.Delay(10000);` line

Comment: None. Use some transactional means for such critical tasks, for example populate some SQL/Redis/RabbitMQ queue with send requests and process them in separate worker, without forget. Fire and forget is usefull for non-critical or repeatable tasks: logging, UI updates, telemetry, life prolongation strategies, retryable tasks, etc

Comment: Take a look at this: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my project, I have a network call to sending Email, I don't want to wait for the response, because the most likely Email provider sends the Emails successfully.

Most email providers work by having you send into a *queue*, and then the actual email is sent later, when they process work out of that queue. So, sending into the queue is fast and very reliable.

So this means that your `SendEmailAsync` or whatever API should be quite fast, and shouldn't require returning early. Since `SendEmailAsync` actually sends to a *queue*, the only thing it represents is "please accept my *request* to send this email".

> Which of the following methods is better and what is the difference?

Neither.

Since sending emails is just a queue write, and you don't want your request to be lost, the appropriate approach is not to use fire-and-forget at all:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    await SendAsync();
    return View();
}

private async Task SendAsync()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Before");
    await Task.Delay(10000);  // Email send
    _logger.LogInformation("After");
}
```

If, for some reason, you're using an email provider that *doesn't* queue, then you can create your own queue (Azure Storage Queue, Amazon SQS, RabbitMQ, etc) and change `SendAsync` to write a message to that queue. Then have a separate background process (Azure Function, Amazon Lambda, etc) read from that queue and send the emails to the email provider.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent. Even though there are many who advise against using this pattern - if you know what you are doing (like logging, taking care to handle all exceptions within the task, taking care that the background task behaves correctly during application shutdown etc.), from my experience it is actually ok to use this pattern, at least in .NET Core.
There are cases where it's not possible or practical or feasible (performance-wise) to handle the background task in a persistent manner (with a DB or a queue).

In fact, [Microsoft's implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs) of `BackgroundService` works exactly like that:

```
        public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Store the task we're executing
            _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

            // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
            if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                return _executingTask;
            }

            // Otherwise it's running
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Here, `ExecuteAsync` is an abstract Task (to be overriden by the subclass) that is run without `await`. The task is stored in an instance field just so it can be cancelled with a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: I've been trying to use this but by creating a "fire and forget tasks" service where a Task can be sent in as a parameter. Would you just take that Task and wrap it inside a Task.Run inside ExecuteAsync?  Or use _executingTask.RunSynchronously?